# Access json file data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http

I've created a json file in the website myjson.com.
Here's the url : [json file](https://api.myjson.com/bins/udmp1)

Now when I try to access data like this : https://api.myjson.com/bins/udmp1/dishes, it doesn't work. But localy It works perfectly.

Now the code I'm using :

```
.constant("baseURL", "https://api.myjson.com/bins/udmp1")
.service('dishesFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function ($resource, baseURL) {

    return $resource(baseURL + "dishes/:id", null, {
        'update': {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });

           }])
```

What did I do wrong ?

Thank you!

Comment: Coz the url is https://api.myjson.com/bins/udmp1 and you can't access a key like that at all.

Comment: How can I access the key then ? When I do it locally it works.

Comment: Are you trying to load the JSON from a different domain, or from a page on myjson.com? If you need cross-domain requests, you might want to look into JSONP: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Comment: @Connum the server gives a response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`  so no need to mess around with JSONP :D

Comment: @armnotstrong good to know, I'm not familiar with myjson. :)

Comment: does the server allow you to update the resource? ie, does the server has implement the `PUT` method?

Comment: Yes, the server allows the PUT request. http://myjson.com/api

Comment: Any help please ?

Comment: @Squaregus did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to get `dishes` data, You should do next:

```js
$.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/udmp1', function (a){
 
  var dishesList = $('ul#dishes');
  
  $.each(a.dishes, function (c,d){
    dishesList.append("<li>"+d.name+"</li>")
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Dishes</p>

<ul id="dishes">
</ul>
```

As `Content-Type` of this response is `application/json` - no need to do `a = JSON.parse(a)` to get parsed data as object.

`a` - it's a response promise object, that You can proceed after response will come.

As per `AngularJS`, You should do next:

```js
var app = angular.module('testMod', []);

app.controller('TestController', function ($scope, $http){
  $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/udmp1').then(function (a){
      $scope.dishes = a.data.dishes;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="testMod">
<div ng-controller="TestController" >
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="dish in dishes" ng-bind="dish.name"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using angular. I updated the post with my code. How should I do it then ?

Comment: NP. WIll be there in minute

Comment: I'm using ngresource ... Any way to do it instead of $http ? Thanks

Comment: @Squaregus, Yes, there is

Comment: Well That's what I'm trying to do, but I can't. Can you sho me how ?

Comment: @Squaregus, try to add `?key=dishes` or `hash` as `#` in the end. Then parse it after query.

Comment: Nah, this is only one way - through `$http`. Resources generally using in internal API's. Not when You are making calls to external sources

Comment: I don't know about that! Thanks anyway I'll try with $http

Comment: @Squaregus, let me try it on local

Comment: Wow thank you.
 And for the POST, PUT, and DELETE ? Do you have a link or some code ?

Comment: @Squaregus, don't need to. Just replace `.get` with method You want use to.

Comment: Well for the put for example, I need to specify which dish to update .... ?

Comment: @Squaregus, ofc You need to. for this stuff You should provide something like `ngRoute` and middleware to strict Your application. You should pass an object like `{a: 1, b:2}`. Then Your controller/service should iterate Your dishes and update fields You specified

Comment: @Squaregus Here You are :) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: I hope you noticed I was not the only one to downvote that answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42115584/2310830

Comment: @RiggsFolly, You are maniac? Why do you chasing me? Go work or do something else.

Answer (score 0):

you should request the url and assign it as object in javascript and then you can access the property like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url:  "https://api.myjson.com/bins/udmp1",
   method: "get",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data){
       var dishes = data.dishes; // now you get dishes
   }
})
```

Comment: I'm using angular. I updated the post with my code. How should I do it then ?

Comment: @Squaregus I am not quite familiar with angular JS, but to use RESTfull interface you should first make sure that the server has implement the RESTfull interface

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('FetchCtrl',function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.method = 'GET';
  $scope.url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/udmp1';

    $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url}).
      success(function(res) {
        $scope.dishes = res.dishes;
        console.log($scope.dishes); // dishes data
      }).
      error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FetchCtrl">
</div>
```

Comment: Your welcome !! Mark this answer is correct so that it will be useful for others also.