# How to append a serialized string that already exists in the database

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I have just started to learn about serialization and I have a question that I cannot seem to find a simple explanation to.

Say I had a table called week and inside week I had 3 columns with the third column containing a bunch of serialized meal IDs like so stored in my database:

```
 INSERT INTO `week` (`week_id`, `meal_code`, `meal_id`) VALUES
(1, 'week12016', 'a:6:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:5;i:6;}');
```

But later I want to append another meal_id to the existing string but not update any other column so it reads

```
(1, 'week12016','a:7:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:5;i:6;i:6;i:7;}')
```

I have tried in a php file to store the following

```
$food=array("7");
$sfood=serialize($food);
```

Then trying to add the 7 to the existing meal_ids in the week table

```
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE week
            SET meal_id ('$sfood')");       
    //if entry into the database is successful, confirm with a alert popup and refresh the home page        
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0){
    //header("location: admin.php");
 header("refresh:0; url=admin.php");
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Upload Successful!')</script>";   
exit;
```

But when I check my database, nothing has changed.

What am I doing wrong, is it even possible to do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: `UPDATE week
            SET meal_id ('$sfood')` you realize that you're trying to update your entire db without a `WHERE` clause. Checking for errors would have helped you here with `mysqli_error($conn)`. It's also failing you, RTM https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html where you're using incorrect syntax.

Comment: I'd probably recommend get the column, unserialize, add data, re-serialize, and then `UPDATE ... WHERE`. Otherwise, you'll either overwrite the data or render it invalid.

Comment: Plus, if you want to append in an update, you need to use either `CONCAT()` or `CONCAT_WS()`  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html if that's what the question is about.

Comment: Serialised strings in database tables are bad.  They violate 1NF and in the long run are just more trouble than they're worth.  Case in point, you wouldn't be having this problem with a better database design.  Refactor your database with foreign keys, linking tables, etc.  You'll thank me in the long run.

Comment: Sure, this was more a question regarding understanding serialization better and the limitations I appreciate what I am asking might not be best practice but like I said I'm just learning about serialization and have given a hypothetical scenario rather than one based on an actual design I am undertaking.

Comment: `UPDATE week SET meal_id = '$sfood' WHERE col_x='y'` is the proper syntax here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the column from your table row. Unserialize it into a PHP variable and then add a new occurance to it.

Then serialize the new array and store it back to your database

```
// SELECT from table
$s = 'a:7:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:5;i:6;i:6;i:7;}';

$d = unserialize($s);

print_r($d);

$d[] = 99;
print_r($d);

$s2 = serialize($d);
echo $s2;

// UPDATE table row
```

RESULTS

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 99
)
a:8:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:5;i:6;i:6;i:7;i:7;i:99;}
```

> Storing data like this is not recommended, as it makes this data impossible to process using queries

Comment: Not quite sure why this has been downvoted, it is technically correct (at least as far as serialised data in a database can be correct).

Comment: @GordonM I have upset someone by DVing one of their answers, correctly in my opinion. But then its not the first time for this to happen. I guess its the problem of leaving a comment when I DV'd his answer